# How to call javascript method when loading Android

Tags: javascript, android, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm a beginner at android.

I used javascript method in android. And I want to call it when the app is loaded for first time.

For example,

```
testMethod = function(str) {
  alert("hi" + str);
}//javascript
```

and

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///index.html");
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(androidBridge, "jsinterface");

    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:testMethod('javascript')");
}
```

What I was thinking here is the alert will pop up immediately when I start the app.

But nothing happens.

About this, I have two questions.

1.Can I call and use the javascript method in Android's onCreate method?

2.If it is possible, How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show a popup on start just use the default AlertDialog. see the code below.

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    showMessage("My Message Here", "Title here");
}

private void showMessage(String data, String title){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(data)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // continue
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer! That's good, but what I really want to do is getting the javascript's value and printing it. And finally I will use that value in android. Can I do this by using your answer?

Answer (score 0):

1. check out whether index.html is REALLY loaded. I guess that webview didn't load your html properly, bcz it's not an invalid file path. try file:///mnt/sdcard/index.html.  (or something likely)
2. try to put `mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:testMethod('javascript')")` in view.post or view.postDelayed.

Comment: html page is loaded well but It still does not work. I think, it is probably javascript error. Thank's for your help!